# Order the output of multiple selects in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am new to SQL so this may be a very common/easy question,
I want to order these from highest to lowest rather than Team 1, Team 2, Team 3. See below:

SQL

```
Select (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '1' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team1,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '2' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team2,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '3' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team3,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '4' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team4,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '5' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team5,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '6' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team6,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '7' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team7,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '8' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team8,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '9' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team9,
   (select SUM(Amt) from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '10' and W.Activity = '2' ) AS Team10
```

Right now the result shows like this:

[image]

I want it to show highest to lowest rather than by team name. Can this be done with an Order By? I just can't seem to get it to work.

Team 2 - 597, Team 7 - 540, Team 3 - 467, etc.

Comment: You're returning a single row, so ORDER BY isn't exactly going to work.

Comment: if you return these as rows first, then order them, then finally pivot them, you might get it to work.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like  Aaron Bertrand mentioned above, ORDER BY is not apply to single row.

You may want to change your query like this

```
select T.Team ,SUM(Amt) as TeamTotal
from Tracker W 
JOIN Teams T 
    ON W.Username = T.Name 
where W.Activity = '2'
AND (ISNUMERIC(T.Team) = 1 AND CAST(T.Team AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
GROUP BY T.Team 
ORDER BY TeamTotal DESC
```

Comment: I get "Column 'Teams.Team' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." when trying this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @kcray Shouldn't it be T.Team? I suspect you didn't copy the code sample correctly.

Comment: Worked perfectly and saved me from typing out that long query again, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`Order by` is a row based operation, not column based.  What you could do is convert this query to be row based and order by the value.

```
select * from (
    select SUM(Amt) as Amt, 'Team1' as Team from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '1' and W.Activity = '2' 
    union 
    select SUM(Amt), 'Team2' from Tracker W JOIN Teams T ON W.Username = T.Name where T.Team = '2' and W.Activity = '2'  
    ...) as T
order by Amt
```